# How would the following three equations be solved?

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Assuming we know values of all the coefficients $e_i$.
How would the following three equations be solved?
$$
e_1 \cdot x + e_2 \cdot y + e_3 \cdot z = e_4
$$
$$
e_5 \cdot x + e_6 \cdot y + e_7 \cdot z = 0
$$
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1
$$

I tried the following, but it became way too messy.
$$
z = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}
$$
$$
e_5 \cdot x + e_6 \cdot y + e_7  \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} = 0
$$
$$
(e_6^2 + e_7^2) \cdot y^2 + 2 e_5 \cdot e_6 \cdot x \cdot y + (e_5^2 + e_7^2) \cdot x^2 - e_7^2 = 0
$$
$$
y = \frac{-2 \cdot e_5 \cdot e_6 \cdot x \cdot y \pm \sqrt{4 \cdot e_5^2 \cdot e_6^2 \cdot x^2 - 4(e_6^2 + e_7^2)((e_5^2 + e_7^2)x^2 - e_7^2)}}
{2 \cdot (e_6^2 + e_7^2)}
$$

Comment: Try substituting $z = -\frac{e_5x+e_6y}{e_7}$ in the first and last equations

Comment: And the $$e_i$$ can also be zero?

Comment: if $$e_7\ne 0$$

Comment: The second equation is a plane passing through the origin, while the third equation is a sphere of unit radius centered at the origin.  Intersecting these gives a circle, so the intersection with the first equation (another plane) could give two points, one (tangent) point, or no point at all.  Can you do the algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the first equation by $$-e_7\neq 0$$ and the second by $$e_3\neq 0$$ and adding both we get
$$x(e_3e_5-e_1e_7)+y(e_3e_6-e_2e_7)=-e_4e_7$$
and now you must do case work.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the first two equations for two of the variables in terms of the third, then substitute into the last equation, which  becomes a quadratic in one variable.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. It was still messy, but do-able.